# Unable to compile simulink s function for comedi interfacing on linux lubuntu 64 bit

Tags: lubuntu, compiling, gcc, make

I have created simulink s-function block  for comedi interfacing on windows 32 bit and compliled suceesfully. But I am unable to compile on 64 bit linux-rtai(lubuntu) system. I am getting following errors.

/usr/src/linux-4.14.89/include/linux/falloc.h:13:2: error: ‘__s16’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘._516’?
  __s16  l_type;
  ^~~~~
._516

/usr/src/linux-4.14.89/include/linux/falloc.h:14:2: error: ‘__s16’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘._516’?
  __s16  l_whence;
  ^~~~~
  ._516

/usr/src/linux-4.14.89/include/linux/falloc.h:15:2: error: ‘__s64’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__f64’?
  __s64  l_start; 
  ^~~~~
  __f64

/usr/src/linux-4.14.89/include/linux/falloc.h:16:2: error: ‘__s64’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__f64’?
  __s64  l_len; //s64 /* len == 0 means until end of file */
  ^~~~~
  __f64

/usr/src/linux-4.14.89/include/linux/falloc.h:17:2: error: ‘__s32’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__f32’?
  __s32  l_sysid;
  ^~~~~
  __f32

/usr/src/linux-4.14.89/include/linux/falloc.h:18:2: error: ‘__u32’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__f32’?
  __u32  l_pid;
  ^~~~~
  __f32

/usr/src/linux-4.14.89/include/linux/falloc.h:19:2: error: ‘__s32’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__f32’?
  __s32  l_pad[4]; /* reserved area */
  ^~~~~
  __f32

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   No supported version of Ubuntu/Lubuntu uses the 4.14 kernel

Comment: This is custom vanilla kernel for rtai-5.2  4.14 kernel patch